# Syntax error in Common Table Expression 1

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a common table expression but I got an error.
Could you please help me with that.

```
WITH cte_sales AS(
    SELECT 
      Payments.BankTransaction_Id,
      Payments.Paid * InvoiceLines.TotalPrice / Invoices.TotalPayable AS PaymentAmount,
        FORMAT( Cast(Payments.Paid / Invoices.TotalPayable as Decimal(6,1)) ,'P0') AS PaymentAmount,
      Invoices.TotalPayable,
      Payments.PaymentDate,
      BankTransactions.TransactionDate,
      ProductContracts.Product_Id,
      ProductBases.Name AS ProductName,
      ProductOptionBases.Name As ProductOptionName,
      InvoiceLines.InvoiceLineId,
      CubeOrder.Id AS ContractId,
      ProductContracts.RowID AS ProductContractId
      FROM Payments
    INNER JOIN Invoices ON Invoices.Id = Payments.Invoice_Id
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLines ON InvoiceLines.Invoice_Id = Invoices.Id
    INNER JOIN ProductContracts ON CAST(ProductContracts.ContractID AS VARCHAR(100)) = SUBSTRING(InvoiceLines.InvoiceLineId, 1, 36)
    INNER JOIN ProductOptionBases ON CAST(ProductOptionBases.Id AS VARCHAR(5)) = SUBSTRING(InvoiceLines.InvoiceLineId, 38, IIF (CHARINDEX(':', InvoiceLines.InvoiceLineId, 38) = 0, 999, CHARINDEX(':', InvoiceLines.InvoiceLineId, 38))- 38)
    INNER JOIN ProductBases ON ProductContracts.Product_Id = ProductBases.Id
    INNER JOIN CubeOrder ON CubeOrder.ContractID = Invoices.SubjectID
    INNER JOIN BankTransactions ON BankTransactions.Id = Payments.BankTransaction_Id
    WHERE ProductContracts.Discriminator = 'RecurringProductContract'
    AND Invoices.TotalPayable <> 0 
    )
```

The error message is: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26 Incorrect syntax near ')'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the main query, that you need to add at the end.

For example, a query with a CTE should take the form:

```
with cte_sales as (
  ...
)
select * from cte_sales
```

You are missing that last line.